# Event after data binding using SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net

I have one textbox to search and one FormView in my page:

```
<div runat="server" id="adminArea">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Enter a Member ID :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox><br />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="vgSearch" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TextBox5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid Member Id"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Search" ValidationGroup="vgSearch" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" DefaultMode="Edit" Width="100%" runat="server" DataSourceID="profileInformationDataSource" DataKeyNames="id" >
    <EditItemTemplate>
           <table align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" class="auto-style1" style="margin-top:20px;">
               <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><b><%# Eval("name") %></b>'s Profile</td>
               </tr>
               /**
               ** Many fields are here to bind
               **/
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

To bind above form fields I am using a SqlDataSource:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="profileInformationDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>' SelectCommand="SELECT Top 1 mem.name,mem.img_src,mem.id, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mem.dob, 111) as dob,mem.sex,mem.member_cert_id,mem.address,mem.Country , mem.state,mem.city,mem.zip,mem.phone,mem.mobile,mem.email_id,mem.bank_acc_no,mem.bank_pan_no,mem.account_holder_name,mem.bank_name,mem.bank_code,mem.bank_address,mem.bank_zip,mem.bank_location,mem.bank_country,mem.bank_branch FROM Members as mem where mem.id = @memberId order by mem.id desc"
 UpdateCommand="UPDATE Members SET name = @name, dob = @dob , member_cert_id = @member_cert_id , address = @address , Country = @Country, state = @state , zip = @zip, mobile= @mobile , phone= @phone, email_id = @email_id, bank_pan_no = @bank_pan_no, bank_acc_no = @bank_acc_no, account_holder_name = @account_holder_name, bank_name= @bank_name, bank_code = @bank_code, bank_address = @bank_address, bank_zip =@bank_zip, bank_location = @bank_location Where id= @id " >
        <SelectParameters>
                 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox5" DefaultValue="0" Name="memberId" PropertyName="Text" />
        </SelectParameters>

    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="dob" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="member_cert_id" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="address" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="state" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="zip" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="mobile" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="phone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="email_id" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="bank_pan_no" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="bank_acc_no" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="account_holder_name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="bank_name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="bank_code" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="bank_address" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="bank_zip" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="bank_location" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" />
    </UpdateParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Whenever I click search button fields are filling by the SqlDataSource. Now my problem is that in the FormView I have UpdatePanels for Country, state and city dropdown. So I want to load them from my back-end code.

So I want an event that is fired up after the filling of data.

Comment: Is your problem loading and binding of Country, City and State dropdowns or firing of an event after filling of data? Could you please add code for  Country, City and State dropdowns also?

Comment: @Manpreet I want to know how to fire an event after the completion of filling of fields by SqlDataReader.

Comment: Any field you want to fire an event from must have AutoPostBack="True" and SelectedIndexChanged event handler need to be assigned.

Comment: @Manpreet By using SqlDataSource I am filling the data in fields, like this field <%# Eval("name") %> or <%# Bind("name") %>, I want to fire an event when sqldatasource will complete filling all data. I want to know how I fire an event. I tried OnInserted, OnUpdated on SqlDataSource but its not working.